# Do SwingX components have translation for Arabic, Russian or Greek languages?

Tags: swing, swingx, jxtable

I'm using a JXTable that contains a search functionality when I press CTRL+F.

If I have my locale defined to English or French, the default text of this search window is automatically translated to the active locale. If however I change it to any of the following languages,  Arabic, Russian or Greek, the search window component's text, defaults to English.

Is there a way to define my own translation for this component or any other SwingX component, by putting my own properties file in the classpath?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open the swingx jar file, look for the properties file holding the values you want to translate, and create your own file with the appropriate locale extension. For example,

```
org/jdesktop/swingx/plaf/basic/resources/swingx_ru.properties
```

Comment: @ktulinho you might consider contributing Russian (or other not yet available) properties to our ever-open issue [swingx-518](http://java.net/jira/browse/SWINGX-518)

Comment: @JB Nizet Thanks! Works like a charm :) I was having trouble finding the .properties files.